# Domain and Range of Function Composition

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

> Given:
>
> $a\left(x\right)=e^x$
>
> $b\left(x\right)=\left|x+2\right|$
>
> $c\left(x\right)=\frac{\left(x-2\right)}{\left(x+1\right)}$
>
> What is:
>
> 1. $\left(\frac{a\cdot b}{c}\right)\left(3\right)$
> 2. The domain of $\left(a^{-1}○a^{-1}\right)\left(x\right)$?
> 3. The range of $\left(b○a\right)\left(x\right)$?

I have gotten to the point of being able to solve for function composition. For example, I was able to figure out what $\left(b○a\right)\left(x\right)$ was; however, I do not know how to express the range. Anything is helpful.

So far my answers are:

2. Domain: (1, $\infty $) Range: ℝ
3. Domain: ℝ Range: (2, $\infty $)

Answer (score 1):

In general, range is harder to figure out than domain.  For domain, you determine which elements lead to a problem, like dividing by zero or taking the log of a nonpositive.

For example, $$a^{-1}\circ a^{-1}(x)=\ln \ln x$$
For this to make sense, you need $\ln x >0$, or else the outer log doesn't work.  This arises when $x>1$.

The range of $|e^x+2|$ can be found in pieces.  $e^x$ has range $(0,+\infty)$.  Hence $e^x+2$ has range $(2,+\infty)$.  Taking the absolute value of any of these numbers leaves them all unchanged, so the final range is $(2,+\infty)$.

Comment: Thank you. After reading your answer and solving the problem once again, the domain for the second problem would be (1,+∞)?

Answer (score 0):

Hints for the second and third questions:

- By definition, $a^{-1}$ is the function $\ln$ (natural log). Its domain is $(0,\infty)$ and its range is $\mathbb{R}$. Additionally, $\ln(x)\in (0,\infty)$ when $x\in(1,\infty)$.
- The range of $a(x)=e^x$ is $(0,\infty)$. As $y$ ranges over all positive numbers, what does the quantity $b(y)=|y+2|$ range over?

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you mind giving me a hint for the first problem?